# Is there any way to apply filterExpression first before apply pagination limit in dynamo query operation.?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I found one big issue with dynamodb pagination.
- I perform query operation with following params

```
params = {
            "TableName": "DEV_post",
            "ProjectionExpression": "postId, postType",
            "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":postStatusPublished": "published"},
            "ScanIndexForward": false,
            "Limit": 6,
            "FilterExpression": " postStatus =:postStatusPublished "
        }
```

**this give a result only 4 posts.** bcos it read latest 6 records and then apply filterExpression that is a most uncommon way of pagination.
First 6 record consist 2 unmatched condition record. 
Is there any way to overcome this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do DynamoDB limit after filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138551/how-can-i-do-dynamodb-limit-after-filtering)

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace sir it seem bit same.. bcos i m new user.

Comment: @ashish  dynamoDb is designed in such a way that first pagination happens and then filters will be applied. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915456/dynamodb-filter-expression-not-returning-all-results/52915557#52915557